# function for odds ratio and/or relative risk calculation given list of model summary data in r or sas?

Tags: r, sas, emmeans

I have computed a multinomial regression model in R. However, for reasons out of scope, I would like to compute odds ratios/RR (with confidence intervals) on a categorical interaction term at all margins of the interaction with summary() data (such as the list of coefficients and standard errors etc.). At this point I would be willing to do it in either R or SAS. To illustrate my point:

```
emmeans(model, var1|var2)
```

is the only thing I can see where `model` is a model object, but instead is there a function where I can act on a data frame output by df<-summary(model)?:

want:

```
emmeans(df, var1|var2)
```

At this point I'd be willing to extract df as an excel file and analyzing in SAS if there is such a way, so any experts are welcome to help. It should be possible because I have the coefficients, terms, and standard errors to compute OR/RR, I think.

Thanks!

Comment: It may be possible, or maybe not. But show a small example dataset and reproducible code for fitting a model. BTW, the syntax you show for emmeans is incorrect. You need a formula for the specs. And the second one definitely won't work because you need a fitted model.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that may be suitable. It's adapted from an example for `nnet::multinom`

Data and model:

```r
library(nnet)
library(MASS)
library(emmeans)

bwt <- with(birthwt, {
    race <- factor(race, labels = c("white", "black", "other"))
    ptd <- factor(ptl > 0)
    ftv <- factor(ftv)
    levels(ftv)[-(1:2)] <- "2+"
    data.frame(low = factor(low), age, lwt, race, smoke = (smoke > 0),
               ptd, ht = (ht > 0), ui = (ui > 0), ftv)
})

bwt.mu <- multinom(low ~ ., bwt)
## # weights:  12 (11 variable)
## initial  value 131.004817 
## iter  10 value 98.029803
## final  value 97.737759 
## converged
```

Here are the estimated marginal means for `low` (the response) given `race`. These are on the "prob" scale by default.

```
(EMM <- emmeans(bwt.mu, ~ low | race))
## race = white:
##  low  prob     SE df lower.CL upper.CL
##  0   0.466 0.0827 11   0.2837    0.648
##  1   0.534 0.0827 11   0.3523    0.716
## 
## race = black:
##  low  prob     SE df lower.CL upper.CL
##  0   0.262 0.0769 11   0.0932    0.432
##  1   0.738 0.0769 11   0.5682    0.907
## 
## race = other:
##  low  prob     SE df lower.CL upper.CL
##  0   0.334 0.0726 11   0.1747    0.494
##  1   0.666 0.0726 11   0.5059    0.825
## 
## Results are averaged over the levels of: smoke, ptd, ht, ui, ftv 
## Confidence level used: 0.95
```

I'm not sure what odds ratios you want, but the route to getting odds ratios is to re-scale everything to the logit scale.

```
REMM <- regrid(EMM, "logit")
```

Now we can get odds ratios for the responses:

```
pairs(REMM, type = "response")
## race = white:
##  contrast    odds.ratio    SE df null t.ratio p.value
##  low0 / low1      0.760 0.505 11    1  -0.414  0.6871
## 
## race = black:
##  contrast    odds.ratio    SE df null t.ratio p.value
##  low0 / low1      0.127 0.101 11    1  -2.600  0.0247
## 
## race = other:
##  contrast    odds.ratio    SE df null t.ratio p.value
##  low0 / low1      0.253 0.165 11    1  -2.111  0.0585
## 
## Results are averaged over the levels of: smoke, ptd, ht, ui, ftv 
## Tests are performed on the log odds ratio scale
```

Or we can turn the tables and get them for comparing the races:

```
pairs(REMM, by = "low", type = "response")
## low = 0:
##  contrast      odds.ratio    SE df null t.ratio p.value
##  white / black      2.449 1.010 11    1   2.172  0.1204
##  white / other      1.734 0.602 11    1   1.587  0.2914
##  black / other      0.708 0.301 11    1  -0.812  0.7034
## 
## low = 1:
##  contrast      odds.ratio    SE df null t.ratio p.value
##  white / black      0.408 0.168 11    1  -2.172  0.1204
##  white / other      0.577 0.200 11    1  -1.587  0.2914
##  black / other      1.412 0.599 11    1   0.812  0.7034
## 
## Results are averaged over the levels of: smoke, ptd, ht, ui, ftv 
## P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 3 estimates 
## Tests are performed on the log odds ratio scale
```

In the latter, since there are only two multinomial categories, the second set of odds ratios is the reciprocal of the respective ones in the first set. So really only 3 tests are done, not six. *And* in the first set, we really get the *squares* of the odds ratios -- for example, the odds ratio for `race = white` is not .466/.534 as we might expect, but rather (.466/.534) / (.534/.466). Dependencies like this make it a little tricky to create and interpret sensible odds ratios with multinomial models.

<sup>Created on 2022-09-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

#### Afterthought

I think maybe it makes more sense to regrid to the log scale rather than logit...

```r
LEMM <- regrid(EMM, "log")

pairs(LEMM, type = "response")
## race = white:
##  contrast    ratio    SE df null t.ratio p.value
##  low0 / low1 0.872 0.290 11    1  -0.414  0.6871
## 
## race = black:
##  contrast    ratio    SE df null t.ratio p.value
##  low0 / low1 0.356 0.141 11    1  -2.600  0.0247
## 
## race = other:
##  contrast    ratio    SE df null t.ratio p.value
##  low0 / low1 0.503 0.164 11    1  -2.111  0.0585
## 
## Results are averaged over the levels of: smoke, ptd, ht, ui, ftv 
## Tests are performed on the log scale
```

The above are actually the odds ratios rather than their squares because we are back-transforming log(p) - log(1-p) = logit(p).

Going the other way, we obtain ratios of probabilities:

```
pairs(LEMM, by = "low", type = "response")
## low = 0:
##  contrast      ratio    SE df null t.ratio p.value
##  white / black 1.774 0.498 11    1   2.044  0.1477
##  white / other 1.392 0.293 11    1   1.572  0.2976
##  black / other 0.785 0.238 11    1  -0.800  0.7109
## 
## low = 1:
##  contrast      ratio    SE df null t.ratio p.value
##  white / black 0.724 0.109 11    1  -2.134  0.1280
##  white / other 0.803 0.116 11    1  -1.522  0.3188
##  black / other 1.108 0.138 11    1   0.827  0.6947
## 
## Results are averaged over the levels of: smoke, ptd, ht, ui, ftv 
## P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 3 estimates 
## Tests are performed on the log scale
```

Comment: thanks Russ, this is great but I really think the problem is I am working with survey data (which is why I was hoping I could pass the output coefficients/SE to emmeans somehow). I tried ```svrepmisc::svymultinom``` but my error says emmeans can't handle “svrepstatmisc”. Nor can it handle svy_vglm :/

Comment: The table of coefs and SEs is not enough information to get what you want, regardless of other concerns.